# Variable value getting changed after a function call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop, pass-by-reference

I am observing a weird behavior in variable values between python functions and I couldn't understand the proper reason behind it. I have two functions like below

```
def a():
    seg_map = np.zeros([224,224],dtype=float)                                                                                                                           
    while True:
      print("Calling expand foreground method")
      new_seg_map = expandforeground2(seg_map,cams_dict[name],z,seg_result,hypercols)                                                                                             
      print(seg_map)                                                                                                                                                              
      print(np.array_equal(seg_map,new_seg_map))                                                                                                                                  
      if np.array_equal(new_seg_map,seg_map):
                print('break')
                break
      seg_map = new_seg_map 

def expandforeground2(seg_map,cam_map,layer_no,seg_result,hypercol_result):
        threshold = np.amax(hypercol_result) * 0.8
        temp_map = seg_map
        #do some manipulations on temp_map 
        return temp_map
```

Now, after calling `expandforeground2` function from function `a`, I see that `seg_map` value in function `a` is getting modified to the value in `expandforeground2` function and `np.array_equal(seg_map,new_seg_map)` is always `True`. I do not understand why this is happening. I have seen some related questions but none of them solve my problem. Can someone explain me the reason behind this and how should I solve this issue?

I want the values of `seg_map` in function `a` to remain unchanged and the return value from `expandforeground2` function should be stored in `new_seg_map`.

Comment: its probably because you just return a reference of `seg_map`. if you  do`temp_map = seg_map` you dont have two lists. you have two references pointing on the same list object. you probably have to make a copy using `temp_map  = seg_map.copy()` before returning

Comment: @luigigi, But why does `seg_map` changes , why is `pass by reference` happening here? It's not the usual behavior right? And can you please elaborate on making a copy before returning. I don't want `seg_map` to change here.

Comment: @luigigi, I tried your answer, but unfortunately I still have the same issue.

Comment: obviously you have to copy the list before manipulating and not before returning. i messed that up in my first answer

Comment: In Python, object variables are pointers to objects. So when you `return temp_map` you're just returning the same object that was passed in. If you want that function to return a modified copy, you need to explicitly create a copy like another poster suggested.